# Can we send notification on android using javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager

Tags: android, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, javapns

Can we send notification on android phone using javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager. If yes then how to initialize Connection for Android like shown below for Apple:-

```
`AppleNotificationServer server =
      new AppleNotificationServerBasicImpl(keystore, password, production);
pushManager.initializeConnection(server);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JavaPNs was written to connect to Apple's APNS servers and send Apple Push Notifications. It doesn't support Google Cloud Messaging for Android, which have a completely different API.